# Mac ssh terminal set echo on after connection

Tags: macos, mac

I have a custom ssh server implemented. Where I have not handled echo, ie once a user connects and logins successfully using client lets say Putty he will not be able to see the characters he is typing in putty window.

In order to see the characters user has to go to change settings Terminal >> turn the local echo force on. Once user does this, he will be able to see what ever he is typing. In putty we can do this at any point after connection.

Now once I connect through Mac ssh client (Terminal) is it possible to change the settings like we have in putty after connecting to server?

Its possible when I try to connect, at the very beginning I just have to give a echo command, but can we do it in between like we do in putty?

Am a first time Mac user, generally work on Windows systems. Might be a very easy way, but have searched and dint find a way.

Comment: I've gotta ask....why are you disabling remote echo?    It's meant as an "error check" for the user to make sure what is being sent is actually received.

Comment: You might want to try `screen` - it's built into macOS and by default, echo *should* be turned on.  I can't test, because I don't have an SSH server that requires local echo.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest transition is probably to just install Putty for Mac. This way you'll be using the program you're already used to with the local echo functionality you want.

You can install Putty for Mac from Homebrew. First install HomeBrew, then run:

```
brew install putty
```

to install putty.